# Creating executable file using pyinstaller not working with subprocesses defined

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have been trying to bundle my code into an .exe file using pyinstaller and have been unsuccessful in wrapping my scripts in a "Main.py" file. I've employed work-arounds to get the scripts packaged into one executable, but now need to add another script to the program which imports custom modules, so I am back to square one.

I tried to pass the arguments to the paths, and hidden-imports without success, formatted as follows:

```
pyinstaller --onefile Main.py
pyinstaller --onefile --paths=path/to/anaconda/envs/ExampleVirtualEnvironment/Lib/site-packages Main.py
pyinstaller --onefile --paths="paths=path/to/anaconda/envs/ExampleVirtualEnvironment/Lib/site-package" --hidden-import=requests --hidden-import=pandas --hidden-import=numpy Main.py
```

I also tried to edit the Main.spec file to define the hidden imports, and pathex arguments again, without success.

A workaround is to pass all files to the main.spec file, and create the executable with the following command however that does not seem to be the best solution.

```
pyinstaller Main.spec
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work, so that I can pass Main.py to pyinstaller, and bundle the code this way?